# linq groupby count returning zero if no records found. But I want empty list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and I am trying to return count by using group by. Below is the LINQ query:

```
var data = from i in table
           where i.Date != null
           group i by new { 
              LineOfBusiness = i.LOB != null ? i.LOB.ReferenceName : string.Empty, 
              COE = i.COE != null ? i.COE.ReferenceName : string.Empty } 
              into g 
              select new
              {
                LineOfBusiness = g.Key.LineOfBusiness,
                COE = g.Key.COE,
                MTD = g.Count(a => a.Date >= startDate && a.Date <= endDate),
                YTD = g.Count(a => a.Date >= YTDStartDate && a.Date <= endDate)
              };
```

***I am getting below result based on dates***

```
LineOfBuiness  |    COE     | MTD  |  YTD
---------------+------------+------+-------
       A       |     X      |  0   |   0
       B       |     Y      |  0   |   0
```

If there is some value for MTD or YTD no issues but If MTD & YTD is zero for all rows, then I want null result. How can I get that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var data = from i in table
       where i.Date != null
       group i by new { 
          LineOfBusiness = I.LOB?.LOB.ReferenceName ?? string.Empty, 
          COE = i.COE?.ReferenceName : string.Empty } 
          into g 
          select new
          {
            LineOfBusiness = g.Key.LineOfBusiness,
            COE = g.Key.COE,
            MTD = g.Count(a => a.Date >= startDate && a.Date <= endDate),
            YTD = g.Count(a => a.Date >= YTDStartDate && a.Date <= endDate)
          };

data = data.All(x => x.MTD == 0 && x.YTD == 0) ? null : data;
```